# DELETE MethodNotAllowedHttpException with IIS, AngularJS and Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5, iis-express, http-status-code-405

I am learning AngularJS 1.5.8 + Laravel 5.3.17 + PHP 7 hosted on IIS/Windows 10, following this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-time-tracker-with-laravel-5-and-angularjs-part-2).

While sending a HTTP AngularJS $resource.delete() to Laravel, I get an error: `405 Method Not Allowed` and the below Laravel error message:

[image]

`php artisan route:list` gives me the following routes table. I expect DELETE to route to `time.destroy`.

[image]

On IIS, I have tried to set PHP to handler to accept all HTTP verbs to no avail.

[image]

IIS request filtering to explicitly allow DELETE also not working.

[image]

HTTP GET and PUT verbs works fine. How can I enable DELETE verb?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By any chance, do you have a middleware that's changing the HTTP verb of the request?

Comment: As I am just learning, the abovementioned tutorial does not use middleware. So I believe it is just the defaults in Laravel, if anything.

Comment: Alright, could you just try to add the middleware to your `routes.php` to check if it's being overwritten by any chance? `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'prefix' => 'api'], function() {...` **<= there!**

Comment: I use laravel and anjular.js, when i delete resource, $http.delete("url") works well.

Comment: I had this issue before on Apache server. Basically, the browser sends a preflight request to the server each time before the actual request under a flag "OPTIONS", so make sure that the IIS server accepts that as well (by default it accepts GET and POST)

Comment: @sina I don't have a routes.php file. I only have routes/web.php, routes/api.php and routes/console.php. I also tried all the other methods mentioned to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason is because i was passing id:null value to Laravel, accidentally.

```
var Time = $resource('api/time/:id'); //using angular-resource.js
Time.delete({id:null}).$promise.then(function(success) {
    console.log(success);
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error); // HTTP error 405, Method Not Allowed
});
```

The 405 error message return is indeed misleading. I wonder how I can override this behaviour and return a more meaningful error message.

Hope this helps other poor souls to look at the correct places without wasting 2 days of searching web server docs!